# AJAX url - external php not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

Basic question, complex headache.
Trying to build a phonegap app, I have a section where a user inputs multiple emails to register, together with a title.

```
<input type="text" name="person[]">
```

Then, Ajax takes care of that,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //url: "php/insert_teams.php",
    url: ip + "php/insert_teams.php",
    data: datastring,
    cache: false,
});
```

Notice I have a comment on the first **url** which is what I used when working locally and everything was ok. Now, I uploaded the file to a domain and the **datastring** ( which is sent correctly as it was with the local PHP) is not treated correctly by the PHP file.

```
<?php
    $person=$_POST['person'];
    var_dump($person);
?>
```

This is what I get through Chrome's developer tools > network > Headers > Form Data when I call the url:

> name:qwe
>  person[]:ana@exemplo.com
>  person[]:email@exemplo.com
>   person[]:bla

which seems ok to me. Then this is what I get in response:

> string(3) "bla"

For some reason, when using the external php it only returns me the last element of the array, always. Am I doing something wrong? Forgetting some detail?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: could be a matter of `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(datastring);` ? Then send the jsonString in data.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery serialize to send array inputs:

```
var myInputValues = $('#yourInput').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //url: "php/insert_teams.php",
    url: ip + "php/insert_teams.php",
    data: {'key' : myInputValues),
    cache: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, the datastring was already a Serialize. It seems that when using external php, chrome's ripple emulator doesn't do the job, and only works through the use of phonegap developer app on your phone.

I'm unable to delete the question now, so hopefully this could help somebody else.

Comment: u should not delete the question, maybe another person has the same problem and now he/she has a solution. (sharing is caring:P)